# Force orientation change for iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I'm trying to change tablet orientation via Screen Orientation API (https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-screen-orientation-api-uses-javascript-to-rotate-the-screen-89639/). It works perfectly on any Android tablet.

But in case of iPads, it throws error:

Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'screen.orientation.lock')

Is there some way to change tablet orientation for iPad?

```
async function rotate() {
  try {
await fullScreen();
} catch (err) {
 console.error(err);
}
 await screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
}

function fullScreen() {
  if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
   document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
 }
}
```